# React native Textinput - Treat Entire word when one character of that word is deleted

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

The question is pretty clear.

Example - In whatsapp, while tagging/mentioning group members in a  group, it appears as

`@john wick`

1. If you put cursor between word, cursor moves to start or end , not in between
2. If cursor is kept at end, and `k` is deleted, entire `@john wick` is deleted.

1 is not a mandatory requirement but 2 is needed

Any hints , react native experts ?

Thanks

Comment: For manipulating the cursor position see https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#selection and https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#onselectionchange. For deleting the entire word of a tag, you will need to implement your https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#onchangetext handler in a way that knows what tags exist in a text input, where they start and end and how to update the value of the TextInput if the last (or any?) character of a tag is deleted.

Comment: thanks for your response, your answer is high-level but it will help to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

1. Put the starting and ending indexes of words in an array. `arr = [{start:2, end:5}, {start:8, end: 10}, ...]`
2. Using @azundo's comments below question, if current cursor/selection is between any of array's element, set the selection start & end to starting & ending index of word respectively. You have to do this on `onSelectionChange`